# Grails time duration formatting tag library

Tags: grails, formatting, gsp, taglib

Grails has 3 clean formatting tag libraries:

- formatDate
- formatNumber
- formatBoolean

Wonder if there is one to format seconds into HH:MM:SS? or if there is another elegant way to format seconds in the rendered view.

**Note:**

`formatDate` does not work since there might be more seconds than `86400`. 
So for a duration of `86461` `formatDate` will return a `00:01:01` where in fact it should be `24:01:01`.

Comment: There is not built in tag library in Grails to do so. However, there are lots of Java libraries that handle displaying time and durations that you could use to implement your own tag library.

Comment: `% 86400` then maybe?  i hope there are no leap somethings around 0 A.D. ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a tag lib: Put `SecondsTagLib.groovy` into `grails-app/taglib/` (both the location, and the suffix `TagLib` in the class name do matter).

```
class SecondsTagLib {
  def formatSeconds = { 
    attrs, body ->
      final int hours = attrs.seconds / (60 * 60)
      final int remainder = attrs.seconds % (60 * 60)
      final int minutes = remainder / 60
      final int seconds = remainder % 60

      out << hours.toString().padLeft(2, "0") + ":" + minutes.toString().padLeft(2, "0") + ":" + seconds.toString().padLeft(2, "0")
  }
}
```

and use that taglib in your view:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Seconds: ${seconds} = <g:formatSeconds seconds="${seconds}"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

the controller's method could look like this:

```
class TagLibController {
  def seconds() { 
    // 10:11:01
    def seconds = (10 * 60 * 60) + (11 * 60) + 1
    def model = ["seconds": seconds]
    render(view: "seconds", model: model)
  }
}
```